# Differentiate $\tan x\tan^{-1}x$

Tags: derivatives

How do I differentiate $\tan x\tan^{-1}x$? Can I cancel them or do I use cross product?

Comment: You can't "cancel" a product of inverse functions.

Comment: First, you have to know what $\tan^{-1} x$ means.  If it means $\arctan x$, then **no**, you cannot cancel.  (If you do not know what it means, then you will be unable to do any calculations with it.)

Comment: The inverse function of $f(x)$ is not the reciprocal of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the product rule. Using this we obtain $\sec^2 x \tan^{-1} x + \frac{\tan x}{1+x^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

$\tan^{-1}$ is the inverse function $\tan$. $\tan^{-1}x$ is the angle that has tangent ratio equal to $x$ and it is not equal to $\dfrac1{\tan x}$. We cannot cancel $\tan x$ with $\tan^{-1}x$.

To do the differentiation, we need the product rule.